# React Redux arrow function not compiling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I created new React&Redux project with `npx create-react-app my-app --template redux`.

From below code i getting following Error: `Parsing error: Invalid parenthesized assignment pattern.`

After switching arrow function to expression everything works fine.

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const movieSlice = createSlice({
  name: "movie",
  initialState: { value: { title: "", descripion: "" } },
  reducers: {
    getMovies: (state, action) = () => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

export default movieSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have added and extra () = by mistake i guess. Here is the solution

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const movieSlice = createSlice({
  name: "movie",
  initialState: { value: { title: "", descripion: "" } },
  reducers: {
    getMovies: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

export default movieSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how i didn't noticed it..

Comment: no problem, it happens all the time :)